# WebWorker側のWebSocketの関数をHookする

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, websocket, web-worker

WebWorker(Dedicated Worker)側のWebsocketのコンストラクタと`onmessage`をHookする事はできますか?

Main thread であればJavaScript ProxyでHookできますが、これをWebWorker側のWebsocketに対して行いたいです。

WebWorkerの`window`はMain threadのものとは違うオブジェクトなのでMainの方でProxyを使ってもWebWorker側には反映されません。

どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

ターゲットのワーカー上で `globalThis.WebSocket = MyWebSocket;` のようなコードを実行すれば可能です。

ワーカーで動かすコードを修正できない場合は不可能だと思います。

Comment: やはりそうなのですね。プロキシサーバー立てワーカーのコードを取得するリクエストをhookするしかないでしょうか?

Comment: そうですね。プロキシを立てるか、もしかしたら service worker の fetch イベントで可能かもしれません。

Comment: ブラウザ拡張機能の webRequest でもできそうですね。